Why Codespaces Port Forwarder asks for password to forward port 443 on macOS?
Why Codespaces Port Forwarder (from VSCode) in macOS needs me to enter my password (not even fingerprint is available) every time it starts a Codespace session when forwarding port 443? Any other app/process can grab and listen on port 443 without asking for a password (for example, npm utility htttp-server can listen on port 443 without requiring a password).

If I don't enter a password, it redirects port 443 to a different port number:

If I enter my password, Codespaces successfully forwards port 443 as expected, but it is annoying I have to do that so many times. Any solution to this password requirement?

Ports below 1024 are privileged and need permission.  Your npm must be sudo root.

Got it, looking around, I see I am able to do so with http-client because Homebrew installed npm under my user account. Any way to get the same privilege for vscode?  Can I move the application somewhere else?
